# Create AD User from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

i have code to create user directly in active directory for ADFS
my sample code -

```
            PrincipalContext principalContext = null;
            try
            {
                principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);


                UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, txt_username.Text);


                if (usr != null)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(txt_username.Text + " already exists. Please use a different User Logon Name.");

                }
                else
                {
                   UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext);


                    userPrincipal.Surname = txt_lastname.Text;
                    userPrincipal.GivenName = txt_firstname.Text;


                    userPrincipal.EmailAddress = txt_email.Text;

                    userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = txt_username.Text + "@ad.net";
                    userPrincipal.SamAccountName = txt_username.Text;

                    userPrincipal.DisplayName = txt_lastname.Text + "  " + txt_firstname.Text;
                    userPrincipal.SetPassword(txt_pwd.Text);

                    userPrincipal.Enabled = true;
                    userPrincipal.PasswordNeverExpires = true;


                    userPrincipal.Save();
                    MessageBox.Show("user Created Sucessfully");
              }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to create PrincipalContext. Exception: " + ex);

            }
```

its work fine with window application ,but if i am putting same application in asp.net its throw error -

**userPrincipal Exception:Access is denied**

any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Which user is running the application pool ?

Comment: The MessageBox.Show() function wont' work in ASP.Net, either

Answer (score 1):

It means that the account used to authenticate to Active Directory does not have permissions to create the account.

Unless you specify otherwise, the account used to run ASP.NET application is created by IIS, and doesn't have any permissions beyond the server it is running on. You have two options:

1. Change the IIS application pool to run with a domain account that has permissions to create accounts, or
2. Use a [different contructor for `PrincipalContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext__ctor_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_ContextType_System_String_System_String_System_String_) that accepts a username and password to authenticate, and use credentials that have permissions to create accounts:

```
principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, "DOMAIN\username", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are constructing your PrincipalContext in this line `principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);` make sure to pass additional parameters such as AD server name, username, password, etc. It should iron out any permission issues. The username and password used should have rights to create the user in AD. For example: `principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADSERVER, $"OU=New Users,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=CO,DC=UK", USERNAME, PASSWORD);`